# Windows Forms toolstrip q

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with a tab control. The tab control dock property is set to Fill.

If I place a toolstrip along the top of the screen, the tabs on the tab control are hidden beneath the toolstrip.

How do I include the toolstrip and avoid having the tabs hidden beneath it?

Comment: is the toolstrip also in the dock control and docked to top?  Can you show us the code you are using? (this is a coding site after all ;)

Comment: I have also seen toolstrips magically acquire the property Visible=false presumable via a bug in the IDE (or perhaps the controls themselves), so you might want to double check that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
yourToolStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
yourTabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
yourTabControl.BringToFront();
```

Comment: where do I put this? I tried to put it in my Form1.cs but I get lots of errors.

Comment: @erm_durr put it in your form constructor, of course you have to change all the variables in my code to the corresponding names in your code.

Answer (score 0):

All the problems many developers are having are originating from the order of docking of controls. There is a good and surprisingly little known way of setting the order of docking.

Go to View --> Other Windows --> Document Outline.

In the Document Outline Panel you can see all your controls. Drag and drop to change the order of docking. The only issue I used to have with this is that the order is exactly the opposite of my intuition. But once you see how it works it is great!